# El namespace no se añade en el nombre de los campos de pestañas incluidas con cqinclude

Tags: xml, aem, cq5, namespace

Trabajando con CQ 5.4, he desarrollado un componente que tiene un diálogo con pestañas (tabs) que contienen los mismos campos. Estaba duplicando el código (lo que hacía su mantenimiento un poco complicado) así que decidir separar las pestañas en su propio xml e incluirlas con `cqinclude`.

Leí [aquí](https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/cqinclude-namespace.html) y [aquí](http://aemtuts.com/how-to-create-reusable-dialog-xml/) que es posible definir un namespace y que éste se añadiría como prefijo en los nombres de los campos; pero cuando lo intento, ningún prefijo se añade y por ello los valores de los campos se "duplican" (se consideran el mismo campo y se concatenan sus valores).

Ésta es una versión simplificada de mi código:

dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
          jcr:primaryType="cq:Dialog"
          height="500"
          width="600">
  <items
         jcr:primaryType="cq:TabPanel"
         activeTab="{Long}0">
    <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
      <image0-tab
                  jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                  path="/apps/acme/components/mycomponent/dialogTileTab.cqinclude.namespace.image0.infinity.json"
                  xtype="cqinclude"/>
      <image1-tab
                  jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                  path="/apps/acme/components/mycomponent/dialogTileTab.cqinclude.namespace.image1.infinity.json"
                  xtype="cqinclude"/>
    </items>
  </items>
</jcr:root>
```

dialogTileTab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
          jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
          title="Tile"
          xtype="panel">
  <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
    <buttontitle
                 jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                 defaultValue="Click Me"
                 fieldLabel="Button Text"
                 name="./button"
                 xtype="textfield"/>
    <titlecolor
                jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                defaultValue="blue"
                fieldLabel="Button Color"
                name="./color"
                type="select"
                xtype="selection">
      <options jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
        <o0
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            text="Red"
            value="red"/>
        <o1
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            text="Green"
            value="green"/>
        <o2
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            text="Cadillac Blue"
            value="blue"/>
      </options>
    </titlecolor>
  </items>
</jcr:root>
```

Con esto puedo ver el diálogo y las pestañas correctamente; el problema viene cuando se guarda la información porque los campos en ambas pestañas tienen los mismos nombres y en lugar de guardarse de manera independiente, se concatenan juntos. Por ejemplo, en el campo de texto de la pestaña 1 esribo "texto 1" y en el mismo campo de la pestaña 2 escribo "texto 2"; cuando guardo y reabro el diálogo, el valor en ambos campos será "texto 1,texto 2".

Hasta ahora sólo he hecho cambios en dialog.xml y en el xml de las pestañas. ¿Tengo que cambiar alguna otra configuración en esos (u otros) archivos? ¿Se me ha olvidado incluir algún *bundle*? ¿Qué es lo que falla y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

<sub>Esto es un *cross-post* de una pregunta que tambien he hecho en [StackOverflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38748020/3695983)</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>Traducción aproximada de la [respuesta obtenida para el *cross-post* en StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38758328/3695983) en inglés.</sup>

El problema es que el código que estás intentando usar no es una prestación que venga por defecto en CQ5 o AEM, requiere el paquete ACS AEM Commons y si no lo tienes instalado, no funcionará.

Si te fijas en el propio [enlace que compartiste](http://aemtuts.com/how-to-create-reusable-dialog-xml/) pone (traducido):

> Lo primero de todo, necesitas tener el paquete ACS AEM commons instalado (CQINclude Namespace está disponible a partir de la versión 1.10.2)

Puedes encontrar [aquí](https://github.com/Adobe-Consulting-Services/acs-aem-commons/releases) la versión apropiada de ACS AEM Commons basada en la versión de AEM que tengas instalada.